# django-celery-beat and DatabaseScheduler with a set first run time

Tags: django, celery, django-celery-beat

I want to use django-celery-beat and DatabaseScheduler to create an "email alert" function for users. They should be able to say, when they want to receive these alerts (e.g. every day - 7 AM or every week monday 1 PM).

I've almost figured out how to create the periodic tasks, i.e.

```
>>> PeriodicTask.objects.create(
...     interval=schedule,                  # we created this above.
...     name='Importing contacts',          # simply describes this periodic task.
...     task='proj.tasks.import_contacts',  # name of task.
...     expires=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30)
... )
```

from https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat, but how do I tell it when the first sendout should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field `start_time` in `PeriodicTask` model. You can set a datetime value for it. The task will be first sent after at that time.

```
>>> PeriodicTask.objects.create(
        # skipped
        start_time=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=300)
        # task will be first sent after 5 minutes
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had a problem with it not starting for some reason. Only when I added the `last_run_at=job_alert.start_time - timedelta(days=1),` (assuming that the interval is one day) it finally worked. Not sure why (see https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/259#issuecomment-516425854)